# VB.Net Google Page Speed Api How to change Strategy to Mobile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-pagespeed

I am trying to run a Google pagespeed api request via a VB.Net WindowsForm app and though i can get a response back for the below request i cannot workout how to get it work with a Mobile strategy.

here is my working code for a desktop request:

```
Dim url As String = "http://news.bbc.co.uk"

Dim service = New PagespeedonlineService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
    .ApiKey = "My Api Code", _
    .ApplicationName = "PageSpeedOnline API Sample" _
})

Dim res = service.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed(url).Execute()
```

Here is a link to googles pagespeed page: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started

Note I am visual studio 2012 with Nuget package for the api.

Comment: you can find the answer in this thread. Hope it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291450/google-pagespeed-api-dotnet-net/34292461

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create a `RunpagespeedRequest` object](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pagespeedonline/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Pagespeedonline_1_1v1_1_1PagespeedapiResource_1_1RunpagespeedRequest.html) with the settings you want. `Runpagespeed()` is a virtual method that should be used by the `RunpagespeedRequest` once you create it.

***Untested Code***

```
Dim url As String = "http://news.bbc.co.uk"

Dim service = New PagespeedonlineService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
    .ApiKey = "My Api Code", _
    .ApplicationName = "PageSpeedOnline API Sample" _
 })

Dim res = New RunpagespeedRequest(service, url);
res.Strategy = PagespeedapiResource.RunpagespeedRequest.StrategyEnum.Mobile
res.Runpagespeed(url).Execute()
```

The above code probably won't work, but I think it will get you in the direction in order to set any other properties.

[PagespeedapiResource Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pagespeedonline/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Pagespeedonline_1_1v1_1_1PagespeedapiResource.html#details)
[PagespeedapiResource.RunpagespeedRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pagespeedonline/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Pagespeedonline_1_1v1_1_1PagespeedapiResource_1_1RunpagespeedRequest.html)