# Google PageSpeed API dotnet .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagespeed, google-api-dotnet-client, google-pagespeed

I have set up a basic C# application to run a PageSpeed test on a website that I specify using the Google.Apis.Pagespeedonline.v2 nuget package.

The set up is simple enough and I have a variable that I can specify the url which is then past in to the Service

```
        // Create the service.
        var service = new PagespeedonlineService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "PageSpeed Sample",
            ApiKey = "[API_KEY_HERE]"
        });

        var url = "URL_TO_TEST";

        // Run the request.          
        var result = await service.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed(url).ExecuteAsync();
```

The problem being the .Runpagespeed method ONLY accepts URL. I need to be able to specify, at minimum, the 'Mobile' strategy so I can obtain scores for both Desktop and Mobile. I know this is possible in other libraries but seems to be missing in .NET. Is anybody aware of a way to do this using the .NET library? In the reference documentation it implies that the method accepts further optional parameters but it does not in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Pagespeedapi: runpagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed) has an optional value called strategy

> strategy  string  The analysis strategy to use
>
> Acceptable values are: 
> "desktop": Fetch and analyze the URL for
>   desktop browsers 
>      "mobile": Fetch and analyze the URL for mobile
>   devices

Example:

```
 var request = service.Pagespeedapi.Runpagespeed(url);
 request.Strategy = Google.Apis.Pagespeedonline.v2.PagespeedapiResource.RunpagespeedRequest.StrategyEnum.Mobile;
 var results = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly the answer I was looking for. Kicking myself that I couldn't see that. Thank you very much

Comment: All of the optional values can be added like that.